# How can I test Post Callout with web token's access? HttpCalloutMock

Tags: apex, unit-test, callout, failing-tests, httpcalloutmock

My POST Method (data for web token - is my custom object's fields):

```
public class Token{
public String accessToken{get;set;}    
}

public static String accessTokenBody(){  //our web token (data is in fields)
        Settings__c settings = [SELECT ConsumerKey__c, ClientSecret__c, Username__c, Password__c, SecurityToken__c
                                FROM Settings__c
                                WHERE Name = 'OurSettings'];  
        String consumerKey = settings.ConsumerKey__c;
        String consumerSecret = settings.ClientSecret__c;
        String username = settings.Username__c;
        String password = settings.Password__c + settings.SecurityToken__c;
        String request = 'grant_type=password&client_id=' + consumerKey +'&client_secret=' + consumerSecret +
                         '&username=' + username + '&password='+password;
        return request;
    }

public static String GenerateJSON(Type__c t){
//I will send and post it like a record in another org:
    Map<String, String> fieldMap = new Map<String, String>{
                   'Name' => t.Name,
                   'Desc__c' => t.Type_Description__c};    
    String serialized = JSON.serialize(fieldMap);         
    return serialized;
 }

public static HttpRequest httpRequest(String service){
    String requestBody = accessTokenBody();
    HttpRequest ourRequest = new HttpRequest();
    ourRequest.setBody(requestBody);
    ourRequest.setMethod(service);
    ourRequest.setEndpoint('https://p21.lightning.force.com/services/oauth2/token');
    return ourRequest;
}

public static HttpRequest finalHttpRequest(String token, String method, String endpointUrl){
    HttpRequest finalRequest = new HttpRequest();
    finalRequest.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + token);
    finalRequest.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    finalRequest.setHeader('accept','application/json');
    finalRequest.setMethod(method);
    finalRequest.setEndpoint('https://p21.lightning.force.com/services/oauth2/token' + endpointUrl);
    return finalRequest;
}

public static HttpResponse postCallout(String positionId) {
    Http ourHttp = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = httpRequest('POST');
    //Error is here: 
    HttpResponse response = ourHttp.send(request);      
    Token objAuthenticationInfo = (Token)JSON.deserialize(response.getbody(), Token.class);

    if(objAuthenticationInfo.ACCESS_TOKEN != null){
        Type__c typ = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Type__c WHERE Id =: TypeID];
        HttpRequest finalRequest = finalHttpRequest(objAuthenticationInfo.ACCESS_TOKEN, 'POST', '');
        finalRequest.setBody(GenerateJSON(typ));
        HttpResponse finalResponse = ourHttp.send(finalRequest);
        if(finalResponse.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            System.debug('CREATED:  ' + finalResponse.getBody());
            return finalResponse;
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Mock:

```
@isTest
global class AnimalsHttpCalloutMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest request) {
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        response.setBody('{"Name":"ttt"}');
        response.setStatusCode(200);
        return response; 
    }
}
```

I get an error `System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out`. I try to make the same web token in my test class, but I think it can't see it. Coverage is just on my `getAccess()`, `httpRequest()` and first 4 rows of `postCallout()`:

```
@isTest
private class CalloutTest {


@isTest
static void testPostCallout() {      
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new AnimalsHttpCalloutMock());

    public class Token{
        public String token{get;set;}    
    }

    Settings__c settings = new Settings__c(Name = 'OurSettings',
                                           ConsumerKey__c = '3Mv78JilhgTvnlkjlkjydGLbGpb8xcTB.2lhtT16LdER9QVx_AmoaOb6gN_3OEtHPlvBDzBYWieC189Cp',
                                           ClientSecret__c = '3453453453419024129',
                                           Username__c = 'mail@mail.com',
                                           SecurityToken__c = '6qdfgcdY6ndyURd32J7Ls2VN',
                                           Password__c = 'mypassword1');
    insert settings;
    String consumerKey = settings.ConsumerKey__c;
    String consumerSecret = settings.ClientSecret__c;
    String username = settings.Username__c;
    String password = settings.Password__c + settings.SecurityToken__c;
    String request = 'grant_type=password&client_id=' + consumerKey +'&client_secret=' + consumerSecret +
                     '&username=' + username + '&password='+password;

    Http ourHttp = new Http();
    String requestBody = CalloutClass.accessTokenBody();
    System.debug('request: ' + request);
    System.debug('request2: ' + requestBody);
    HttpRequest ourRequest = new HttpRequest();
    ourRequest.setBody(request);
    ourRequest.setMethod('POST');
    ourRequest.setEndpoint('https://p21.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
    Type__c typ = new Type__c(Name = 'ttt');
    insert typ;
    //System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out
    HttpResponse response = CalloutClass.postCallout(typ.Id);
    String contentType = response.getHeader('Content-Type');
    System.assert(contentType == 'application/json');
    String actualValue = response.getBody();
    System.debug(response.getBody());
    String expectedValue = '{"Name":"ttt"}';
    System.assertEquals(actualValue, expectedValue);
    System.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode());
}    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out` error because **A Web Service Callout may not occur after a DML statement within the same transaction**.

**Solution** :
To achieve the required action, the transaction must be separated into two parts so that the DML transaction is completed before the Web Service Callout occurs. So use `Test.startTest` and `Test.stopTest` to separate context.

```
 Test.startTest(); 
 Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new AnimalsHttpCalloutMock());
 HttpResponse response = CalloutClass.postCallout(typ.Id); 
 Test.stopTest();
```

Comment: I changed it (replace iserting to the top). The same error.

Comment: move these statements Type__c typ = new Type__c(Name = 'ttt');  insert typ;  just after the `insert settings` statment.

Comment: It is after insert settings already. Before `Http ourHttp = new Http();` - same.

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. Coverage is now bigger: on 5 first rows of `postCallout()` and last row `return null;`. Now Error is on `String contentType = response.getHeader('Content-Type'); an`d asserts: `System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object`. I don't understand what it need. If I replace String and asserts into startTest and stopTest - same error.

Comment: Yes,  you should move assertion into startTest and stopTest.

Comment: I think there is issue with line, `ourRequest.setBody(request);` It should be `ourRequest.setBody(requestBody);`

Comment: Same thing. Can it be because of HttpResponse response = CalloutJobAdvertisement.postCalloutResponseContents(pos.Id);?

Comment: I think I got your issue. In your scenario, there are two HTTP callouts and you have mocked only one callout that's why you are getting null exception. Please read out `Testing multiple HTTP callouts` section of this blog (https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/03/testing-apex-callouts-using-httpcalloutmock.html) and implement accordingly.